# How to check typed callback type inside Fragment.onAttach()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, generics, inheritance

I'm trying to implement abstract fragment with typed callback to use it in several subclasses.

**How can I check if Context is instance of appropriate class?**

My code of abstact CallbackFragment:

```
public abstract class CallbackFragment<C> extends Fragment {

    protected C mCallback;

    public CallbackFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        //just in case
        if(context == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();

        try {
            mCallback = (C) context; //this line not seems to throw any exception
        } catch (ClassCastException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement Callbacks");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallback = null;
    }
}
```

Vehicle list fragment:

```
public abstract class VehicleListFragment<T extends Vehicle>
        extends CallbackFragment<VehicleListFragment.Callback<T>> {

    //callback for any list of any vehicle
    public interface Callback<T extends Vehicle> {
        void onListItemSelected(T selectedItem);
    }

    //common code for list of any vehicle
    public VehicleListFragment() {
    }
}
```

Bus, Truck, Boat, Bike, whatever list fragment:

```
public class BusListFragment
    extends VehicleListFragment<Bus> {

    //code specific for list of bus
    public BusListFragment() {
    }
}
```

Vehicle details fragment:

```
public abstract class VehicleDetailsFragment<T extends Vehicle, C extends VehicleDetailsFragment.Callback<T>>
        extends CallbackFragment<C> {

    //common methods of callback for any vehicle
    public interface Callback<T> {
        void onVehicleEdited(T editeItem);
    }

    //common code for any vehicle
    public VehicleDetailsFragment() {
    }
}
```

Bus, Truck, Boat, Bike, whatever details fragment:

```
public class BusDetailsFragment
        extends VehicleDetailsFragment<Bus, BusDetailsFragment.Callback> {

    //specific for Bus methods
    public interface Callback
            extends VehicleDetailsFragment.Callback<Bus> {
        void onSomethingSpecificForBusHappened(Bus bus);
    }

    //code specific for Bus
    public BusDetailsFragment() {
    }
}
```

---

I've tried to add an abstract method for CallbackFragment to get callback class:

```
public abstract class CallbackFragment<C> extends Fragment {

    ...

    @NonNull
    protected abstract Class<C> getCallbackClass();

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        ...

        //now checking instanceof like this
        if(!getCallbackClass().isAssignableFrom(context.getClass())){
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement Callbacks");
        }
    }
}
```

With BusDetailsFragment everything looks OK:

```
public class BusDetailsFragment
        extends VehicleDetailsFragment<Bus, BusDetailsFragment.Callback> {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected Class<Callback> getCallbackClass() {
        return Callback.class;
    }

    ...
}
```

But not with BusListFragment:

```
public class BusListFragment
        extends VehicleListFragment<Bus> {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected Class<Callback<Bus>> getCallbackClass() {
        /**
         * I'm not seeing any option here
         *
         * mCallback - is null yet. So, there is no way to use mCallback.getClass()
         *
         * Callback<Bus>.class - Cannot select from parameterized type
         */
        //return mCallback.getClass();
        //return Callback<Bus>.class;
    }

    ...
}
```

---

Of course, I could create an own interface for every subclass of VehicleListFragment that extends VehicleListFragment.Callback (like in subclasses of VehicleDetailsFragment) but it will always look like this:

```
public interface Callback
        extends VehicleListFragment.Callback<Bus> {
    //nothing more here
}
```

This doesn't look like the best option for me. **Maybe there is any other solution?** Please share your thoughts. ANY help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
mCallback = (C) context; //this line not seems to throw any exception
```

this call will never throw an Exception. During Runtime, your `C` is replaced with `Object`(that's called Type-Erasure) - and everything is an `Object`. Therefore you can assign anything at this point.

To have the exception (or at least error-determination) at the point, where you need it, you can use:

```
public abstract class CallbackFragment<C> extends Fragment {

    protected C mCallback;
    protected Class<C> callbackClass;

    public CallbackFragment(Class<C> clazz) {
       this.callbackClass = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        //just in case
        if(context == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();

        if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(context.getClass()){
            mCallback = (C) context;  
        }else{
           //oops
        }
    }
}
```

ofc. then your FragmentCreation would change from

```
 CallbackFragment<Something> fragment = new CallbackFragment<Something>();
```

to

```
CallbackFragment<Something> fragment = new CallbackFragment<Something>(Something.class);
```

It's a little different, but allows you to keep *track* of the actual type at any time, bypassing the Type-Erasure.

ps.: For *Inherited* classes, you can do it more generic:

```
public abstract class CallbackFragment<C> extends Fragment {
    protected Class<C> callbackClass;

    public CallbackFragment() {
          this.callbackClass = (Class<C>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
                        .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];;
     }
}

public class CallbackFragmentOfSomething extends <CallbackFragment<Something>>{

}
```

This only fails, if your actual class is not defined due to inheritance, but "on the fly":

```
CallbackFragment<Something> fragment = new CallbackFragment<Something>();
```

(Everything untested / no copy paste, but should be somewhat accurate)

Comment: Wow! Thanks. I will try this out. I'm just not shure I've completely understanding your answer right now. Did you noticed that Callback for BusListFragment is  VehicleListFragment.Callback<Bus> and I can't get .class of parameterized type?

Comment: @user2661298 It's quite hard to keep track of Generics using Generics as Types having their own Types while inheriting other Generics with other Types - without beeing able to debug step-by-step. Rule of the thumb: Keep Track of your actual class whenever possible and you can determine actual class types and "cast save" at any time.

Comment: what do you think about creating abstract method CallbackFragment.castCallback(Context context), invoking it inside Callbackfragment.onAttach() and implementing it in each child class to get correct Callback or ClassCastException? Check out my edits for this question (at the bottom) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46750211/java-object-casting-doesnt-work-like-i-need-it-to