# Java object casting doesn't work like I need it to

Tags: java, android, inheritance, parameterized-types

I'm developing native Android app on Java and I faced some unexpected behavior. Look at these classes:

```
public class Parent<C> {

    protected C mCallback;

    public void setCallback(Object callback) {
        mCallback = (C)callback;
    }
}

class Child<T extends Vehicle>
        extends Parent<Child.Callback<Vehicle>>{

    public void invoke(){
        mCallback.onAction(new Vehicle());
    }

    public interface Callback<T> {
        void onAction(T vehicle);
    }
}

class Vehicle {

}
```

And now

```
    Child<Vehicle> child = new Child<Vehicle>();
    child.setCallback(new Object()); // I expect ClassCastException to be thrown here!
    child.invoke(); //But it's thrown only here!
```

**Why ClassCastException isn't thrown in .setCallback() method?**

**Why it is thrown only when I try to access method of Callback interface?**

**How to check Object callback is instance of C? Or how can I at least get ClassCastException in setCallback() method?**

P.S. This is simplified example! Please consider the same, but real life question here: [How to check typed callback type inside Fragment.onAttach()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745858/how-to-check-typed-callback-type-inside-fragment-onattach)

---

One of the solutions proposed by @luckydog32 in comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46750211/java-object-casting-doesnt-work-like-i-need-it-to#46750277)

```
public abstract class Parent<C> {

    protected C mCallback;

    public void setCallback(Object callback) {
        mCallback = castCallback(callback);
    }

    protected abstract C castCallback(Object callback) throws ClassCastException;
}

class Child<T extends Vehicle>
        extends Parent<Child.Callback<Vehicle>>{
    @Override
    protected Callback<Vehicle> castCallback(Object callback) throws ClassCastException {
        return (Callback<Vehicle>)callback;
    }

    public void invoke(){
        mCallback.onAction(new Vehicle());
    }

    public interface Callback<T> {
        void onAction(T vehicle);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's how generics work. Please read up on [reified generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: Also read on `Type-Erasure`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html - that's why your exception is not thrown at cast-time, but at access time.

Comment: Is there any way to check object implements Callback in setCallback() method?

Comment: @user2661298 `if (!(object instanceof Callback)){ //oops }` (to this in a more generic way, peoply often store the `Class<T>` by passing it in the constructor and comparing to that value with the instance of the passed object.)

Comment: No, unfortunately. Callback is C inside setCallback() i cant do (object instanceof C)

Comment: @dognose please look at my other question. Same theme, but more close to real life. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745858/how-to-check-typed-callback-type-inside-fragment-onattach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of something called [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Basically after you program is compiled generic types are replaced with their Upper Bound. So for example

```
class Child<T extends Vehicle>
```

Every instance of T is just treated as if it were a Vehicle class.

So in the code:

```
public void setCallback(Object callback) {
    mCallback = (C)callback;
}
```

During run time you are pretty much saying:

```
public void setCallback(Object callback) {
    mCallback = (Object)callback;
}
```

Since you are casting callback immediately, the simple fix for your code would to just do:

```
public void setCallback(C callback) {
    mCallback = callback;
}
```

Comment: I can't control input type of setCallback() method. This is simplified example. In reality Object is a Context. Please check out my source question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745858/how-to-check-typed-callback-type-inside-fragment-onattach

Comment: Ultimately you are going to have to put some limits on what the method can take in. Perhaps putting an upper bound on C would do the trick with something like `<C extends Context>`

Comment: Interface can't extend Context. I need to check is Context implments some interface or not. In Fragment.onAttach(Context context)

Comment: If you need to check if context implements an interface then why don't you do something like `onAttach(InterfaceYouNeedToExtend context)`

Comment: because Fragment.onAttach(Context context) is method of Fragment that is invoked by System when it attaches Fragment to Context.

Comment: hey! Ther is something very useful in your previous message! I can create abstract method for Parent like checkCallback(C callback), invoke this method in setCallback(Object object), implement this method in child class and get ClassCastException there! What do you think?

Comment: Oh which message?

Comment: I've updated my question. Check it out. What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot cast to a `C`, as it doesn’t exist at runtime (ie compile time only) instead, use C instead of Object in your setCallback definition

Comment: I can't. This is simplified example. In reality Object is a Context. Please check out my source question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745858/how-to-check-typed-callback-type-inside-fragment-onattach

Comment: Use <C extends Callback> syntax